# What is "x-raw-image" in a google image search result?

Tags: image, google-search

I'm trying to automatically process the results of a google similar image search.  I've noticed that some results come back with "x-raw-image:///<48 bytes or so of data>" in the URL for the image.  I think this is happening when the search is extracting an image from a PDF document.  Does anyone know what that data is?  Is it anything that is usable outside of google?  I was hoping that it might be similar to a "data:image" reference, with the image data embedded, but that might not be the case.

Thank you.

ETA: Here is a random example I found that I hope works for everyone:

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=x-raw-image%3A%2F%2F%2F79da01aca79b556defc81ee719442327379e067a26c5c5c9ec104fc39fb70177&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F0706.2165&tbnid=bVWbp6wB2nmBiM&vet=12ahUKEwiD06O97dXuAhWUUM0KHXp7Co0QMygCegQIARAy..i&docid=nD--BiC0InIh_M&w=1600&h=2071&q=physics%20papers%20diagram%20pdf%20x-raw-image&client=firefox-b-1-d&ved=2ahUKEwiD06O97dXuAhWUUM0KHXp7Co0QMygCegQIARAy

This is the frame you get when you click on one of the results in an image search.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example? Both of how you searched and what results you got.

Comment: Good point; I added an example.  Thanks.